# Proof that composition of two unbounded functions is not a bounded function.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing

I am supposed to answer the question if a composition of unbounded functions can be a bounded function. I have failed to find any counter example, so I should probably do a proof by contradiction but I don't know how. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to find functions $f:I\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and $g:J\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that both are unbounded over their domain of definition but so that $g$ is bounded on $f(I)$. That is $g\vert_{f(I)}$ is bounded. Then $g(f(x))$ is bounded.

If $x>0$ then both $e^{x}$ and $1/x$ are unbounded. Can you compose them to get something bounded?

Answer (score 0):

Define $f$ and $g$ by

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)) &=\left\{
   \begin{array}{lr}
      x & \mbox{ if $x \ge 0$} \\
      0 & \mbox{ if $x < 0$}
   \end{array}\right.
\\
g(x)) &=\left\{
   \begin{array}{lr}
      0 & \mbox{ if $x \ge 0$} \\
      x & \mbox{ if $x < 0$}
   \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
$$
Then neither $f$ nor $g$ is bounded, but $f \circ g$ is identically $0$.

Comment: I should make a non specific proof.

Comment: What do you mean by "non specific" proof? The question asks if a composition of unbounded functions can be bounded. A positive answer to that question just requires an example of two unbounded functions whose composition is bounded.